# Setting class of the div to clear after every second occurrence is not working correctly in while loop

Tags: php

I am running in to a problem with

```
$divider_div = ($last_topic % 2 == 0) ? '
<div class="clear"></div>' : FALSE ;
```

that should place  after every second occurrence, but instead it brakes the sequence somehow.

What I am doing incorrectly?

Any suggestions are much appriciated

Here is my script

```
$category_topic_query = 'SELECT l.category_name, l.category_folder, l.category_page, f.parentpageID, f.ImagePath, f.referring_url, f.templateTitle FROM lcategories l INNER JOIN Files f ON f.parentpageID = l.ID WHERE f.pageID = "0" ORDER BY f.parentpageID';
    $resc = $db->prepare($category_topic_query);
    $resc->execute();
$last_topic = NULL;
while ($category_topic = $resc -> fetch()){
    $category_topic_ID = $category_topic['parentpageID'];
    if($category_topic_ID !== $last_topic) {
    $category_topic_name = str_replace("&", "&amp;", $category_topic['category_name']);
    $category_topic_url = DST.$category_topic['category_folder'].DS.$category_topic['category_page'];
    $divider_div = ($last_topic % 2 == 0) ? '
<div class="clear"></div>' : FALSE ;
    $first_ul = ($category_topic_ID == 1) ? FALSE : '</ul>
</div>'.$divider_div ;
print<<<END
$first_ul
<div style="float: left; margin: 10px; width: 349px;">
<h2 class="h_unln"><a href="$category_topic_url">$category_topic_name</a></h2>
<ul class="arrow">

END;

$last_topic = $category_topic_ID;
}
    $links_array = ($category_topic['referring_url'] == NULL) ? FALSE :'<li><a href="'.DST.$category_topic['ImagePath'].DS.$category_topic['referring_url'].'">'.$category_topic['templateTitle'].'</a></li>';


print<<<END
$links_array

END;
}
print<<<END
</ul>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>

END;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does it mean: `it brakes the sequence somehow`?

Comment: What you are trying to do relies on the post ids being consecutive, with no “holes” in between them – never do that! A database id has one purpose, and one purpose only: Identifying a record, nothing else. Just use a simple counter variable instead – initialize it as 0 before the loop, and increase it by 1 in every iteration.

Comment: I have tried that to, like that $add_rowNum = 0; and then $add_rowNum++ inside the loop, but that did not work either, I have had that div appearing after every occurrence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it is done and works as it should and expected

```
    $category_topic_query = 'SELECT l.category_name, l.category_folder, l.category_page, f.parentpageID, f.ImagePath, f.referring_url, f.templateTitle FROM lcategories l INNER JOIN Files f ON f.parentpageID = l.ID WHERE f.pageID = "0" ORDER BY f.parentpageID';
    $resc = $db->prepare($category_topic_query);
    $resc->execute();
$last_topic = NULL;
$add_rowNum = 1;
while ($category_topic = $resc -> fetch()){
    $category_topic_ID = $category_topic['parentpageID'];
    if($category_topic_ID !== $last_topic) {
        $add_rowNum++;
    $category_topic_name = str_replace("&", "&amp;", $category_topic['category_name']);
    $category_topic_url = DST.$category_topic['category_folder'].DS.$category_topic['category_page'];
    $divider_div = ($add_rowNum % 2 == 0) ? '
<div class="clear"></div>' : FALSE ;
    $first_ul = ($category_topic_ID == 1) ? FALSE : '</ul>
</div>'.$divider_div ;
print<<<END
$first_ul
<div style="float: left; margin: 10px; width: 349px;">
<h2 class="h_unln"><a href="$category_topic_url">$category_topic_name</a></h2>
<ul class="arrow">

END;

$last_topic = $category_topic_ID;
}
    $links_array = ($category_topic['referring_url'] == NULL) ? FALSE :'<li><a href="'.DST.$category_topic['ImagePath'].DS.$category_topic['referring_url'].'">'.$category_topic['templateTitle'].'</a></li>';


print<<<END
$links_array

END;
}
print<<<END
</ul>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>

END;
```

my mistake was that I was actually adding `$add_rowNum++;` in the wrong place

Thanks to you all especially CBroe, because he did make me realise one very important thing about ID